# TSA Checked Passengers Daily Data for 2002-2022

Tags: data-request, federal

The TSA has daily checked passenger data on their website for 2019 to present. Where can I find the data for the prior years?

Comment: What about contacting them [using the contact link](https://www.tsa.gov/contact)?

Comment: I tried and it leads to a bot.  The data they present is also messed up - there is a 1 day shift in one year and a 3 day shift in another year. And they're missing Feb 29, 2020.